# I can't search in my script

Tags: php, search, search-engine

Why when I use "ab cdefgh" the script  just read "ab" and Could not read after space ?

```
<?php
$con = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);
if (isset($_GET['c']) and isset($_GET['v'])) {
    $license = $_GET['v'];
    $mac = $_GET['c'];

    $mac_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM app WHERE mac='$mac'");
    $fetch_query = mysqli_fetch_array($mac_query);
    if ($fetch_query == 0 ) {
        $license_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM app WHERE license='$license'");
        if (mysqli_fetch_array($license_query) > 0 && $license !=='') {
            $insert = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE app SET mac='$mac'");
        }
        else { 
            print "Unexpected license";
        }
    }
    else {
        $mac_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM app WHERE mac='$mac'");
        $fetch_mac = mysqli_fetch_array($mac_query);
        if ($fetch_mac['active'] == "") {
            if ($license == $fetch_mac['license']) {
                $query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE app SET active='active' WHERE mac='$mac'");
                echo "Active";
            }
            else {
                echo "Deactive";
            }
        }
        elseif ($fetch_mac['active'] == "active") {
            ?>
            <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search">
            <button type="submit" name="btn-search">Search</button>
            </form>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['btn-search'])) {
                $word = $_POST['search'];
                $select_lic = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM app WHERE mac='$mac'");
                $content_s = file_get_contents("http://ask.com/web?q=$word");
                if (strpos($content_s,"did not match with any Answers results.")) {
                    echo "false";
                }
                else {
                    $select_lic = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM app WHERE mac='$mac'");
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_lic);
                    $word = md5($word).",";
                    if ($row['license'] === $license) {
                        echo "true";
                        $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO words (index) VALUES ('$word')");
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "Error";
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
                echo "";
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    exit;
}
?>
```

For example i search" ab cdefgh"  but
My script only read "ab" and don't read 
"cdefgh" how can i fix it?

Comment: How do you even read your own code with indentation like that?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks. You should first fix that by using prepared statements with bound parameters, then worry about the errors you have above.

Comment: I can't search in this script

Comment: Fix the other errors first and possibly that error will resolve itself.

Comment: How can i fix sql injection?

Comment: @AMIRHOSSEINRAHIMI try to be best friend with google.

Comment: [Look it up](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+i+fix+sql+injection+in+php%3F).